# Android update row problems

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In the app we are putting together I am trying to update rows from different Activities but it is throwing an error or not updating anything because I can't seem to get the current rowId once I move from one activity to the next. Any thoughts would be great.

This comes from the Activity:

```
Cursor value;

db.open();
long rowId = value.getLong(value.getColumnIndex("_id"));
boolean id = db.updateA(rowId, a1, a2, a3, a4);
db.close();
```

If I set the "rowId = 1" it updates that row just fine but I want to get the row that was just created in a different activity.

This is in the DBHelper file:

```
public boolean updateA(long rowId, String a1,String a2, String a3, String a4) {
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

args.put(C_A1, a1);
args.put(KEY_A2, a2);
args.put(KEY_A3, a3);
args.put(KEY_A4, a4);
return db.update(TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the record I would suggest storing the record upon creation in a data object in memory and passing that to the other Activity that needs to do the update.  The data object should have a property for its own ID, so you can just use that.

Not having a reference to the record you need to update will be a disaster.  Also, if you know you always need to update the record, why don't you just do it on insert?

Comment: Thank you both for you input.

Comment: @user712343 - No problem.  If you found an answer that helped you you should accept the answer so that other users that search for the same question can quickly see what was helpful.  You can also upvote answers by clicking the up arrow on the left by each post.  Enjoy Stack Overflow!

Comment: What I did was to put everything on one table and it fixed what I was doing.

Comment: I tried storing it in the database and it works great until the row I am storing it in gets deleted. Do you have an example of a data object that can store this information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that.

You have an activity A that opena a DB, updates a row and closes the DB. This is done with the help of SQLiteOpenHelper class.

Now you move to activity B and now what? Post your primary key (you know it, you used it an A) with putExtra to B (or just put the whole row to B). If you put the rowid to B you can open, reread the row, update if needed and close again. If you just put the whole row to B, well that's all you need to do - but I wouldn't like that (e.g. what happens if B crashes?).

If you update in both activities without knowledge what both activities did (and without re-reading the rows) it's pure luck what you end with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return db.update(TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId + "'", null)
```